# Controller Action with Derived Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, polymorphism, derived-class

I have one base class and two derived classes:

```
public class UserModel {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public UserType UserType {get; set;}
}

public class StudentModel : UserModel {
    public string StudentProperty {get; set;}
}

public class TeacherModel : UserModel {
    public string TeacherProperty {get; set;}
}
```

In my controller ProfileController.cs I have the following two actions:

```
public virtual ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
    var userModel = _userService.Get(id);

    return view(usermodel);
}

public virtual ActionResult Save(UserModel userModel)
{
    _userService.Save(userModel);
}
```

I have one view to show the profile of both Students and Teacher. My problem is the following:

when saving, using the action Save(UserModel userMode), the additional properties of StudentModel and TeacherModel (StudentProperty and TeacherProperty respectively) are obviously not bound to UserModel. So my questio is:

**What is the right way to set up the Controller Action so that I can pass a derived class,  either a StudentModel or TeacherModel?**

FYI, I have tried a custom binder (see below), however, I don't know if this is a good way to handle this.

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;

    switch (form["UserType"])
    {
        case "student":
            {
                var studentModel = bindingContext.Model as StudentModel;                        
                return studentModel;
            }
        case "Teacher":
            {
                var teacherModel = bindingContext.Model as TeacherModel;
                medico.TeacherProperty = form["TeacherProperty"];
                return teacherModel;
            }
    }

    return bindingContext.Model;
}
```

Comment: FYI [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) has some details on creating a custom Abstract Model Binder.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - That's a good article, however I am loathe to allow an incoming request to choose any type it wants to instantiate without some kind of input sanitizing.  It would be better if the AbstractBinder could specify which specific types it was allowed to create, and even better, allow it to interact with an attribute on the action method to define these.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - More importantly, you might want include some kind of security mechanism as well, not allowing certain users or roles to instantiate certain types, even if they might be allowed on that controller.  So the concept, while intriguing needs much more work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem with polymorphic model binding is one of security.  After all, you are effectively allowing the client to control how the data gets interpreted.  You have to be careful that, for example, a user can't modify the post and tell the server that your UserModel is actually an AdministratorModel and that you are now an administrator.

In your use case, I don't know what your app does.. but assuming it's some kind of record keeping application, imagine that a student can make themselves a teacher just by altering the type submitted to the server, and now they can change their own grades, or those of other students.

If, however, this is not really an issue, then a fairly simple mechanism is to simply do this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Save(UserModel userModel)
{
    TeacherModel tmodel = null;
    StudentModel smodel = null;
    if (userModel.UserType == UserType.Teacher) {
        tmodel = new TeacherModel();
        UpdateModel<TeacherModel>(tmodel);
    }
    else {
        smodel = new StudentModel();
        UpdateModel<StudentModel>(smodel);
    }

    _userService.Save((UserModel)tmodel ?? smodel);
}
```

The custom model binder approach you proposed in your question is also fine, and a better choice if this is used in multiple methods, but is not quite so obvious to someone maintaining the application.

In fact, a better solution in a case like this, assuming that your model type is based on some kind of security mechanism, is to instantiate the correct model based on the role of the user.  So, when your request comes in, you check the users permissions, and if they are in the Teacher role, you instantiate a TeacherModel object and if they're a student you instantiate a StudentModel object, and that way there is nothing the end user can do to change how that works.

ie, something like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Save(UserModel userModel)
{
    TeacherModel tmodel = null;
    StudentModel smodel = null;
    // lookup user in database and verify the type of user they are
    var user = UserManager.GetUser(userModel.UserId)
    if (user.Role == "Teacher")
        tmodel = new TeacherModel();
        UpdateModel<TeacherModel>(tmodel);
    }
    else {
        smodel = new StudentModel();
        UpdateModel<StudentModel>(smodel);
    }

    _userService.Save((UserModel)tmodel ?? smodel);
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. I think for my needs it is really an overkill to add a custom binder so I have been trying to just do it directly in the action as you suggested. One problem I am having is that calls to `UpdateModel<TeacherModel>(userModel);` or `UpdateModel<StudentModel>(userModel);` give me a compilation error "Argument type 'UserModel' is not assignable to parameter type 'TeacherModel'" I assume that is because TeacherModel is derived from UserModel and not the other way around. Do you know how can I get around this?

Comment: @GabrielLopez - yeah, I should have double checked that.  See my update

Comment: @GabrielLopez - Note that UpdateModel will throw an exception if validation fails, which you may not want.. so either catch the exception (not ideal) or use TryUpdateModel (the preferred method, which I did not use for simplicity).

Answer (score 1):

I've done this exact behavior before.  What I did was the view would dynamically change the form action based on the type.  Each typed model bound back had an independent method for that type.

So I had models something similar to:

```
public abstract class Property {...}

public class Industrial : Property {...}

public class Commercial : Property {...}

public abstract class Residence : Property {... }

public class Condo : Residence {...}

public class Residential : Residence {...}
```

View:

```
@model Property

@using(Html.BeginForm(Model.GetType().Name, "Property", ...))
{
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PropertyController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Industrial(Industrial model)
  {
    ...
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Commercial(Commercial model)
  {
    ...
  }

  // etc
}
```

My fear over creating a single method with a custom model binder was that I would start to do class specific functionality based on type, which creates a very big method that is responsible for multiple types (which breaks [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

Comment: Thank you Erik. I think this is a viable solution considering I don't have that many derived classes. I am not too concern about breaking Separation of Concerns since my controller only populates the model and my service layer actually calls different providers to manage the logic of each derived class. If I can't get it to work with one action, I will go this route.