# asp.net core WebAPI get subset of Generic Request Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, modelbinders, http-request-parameters

I am new into asp.net core webAPI.
I have created a Controller method that taken a request object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/DoWork")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    public virtual IActionResult DoWork(CustomRequest request)
    {
          //TODO: implement this method 
    }
```

Now this `CustomRequest` calss is generic class, which have multiple properties and depending upon the client/tenant will populate/set values for some of the properties.

Example :
Suppose `CustomRequest` class structure is,

```
public partial class CustomRequest
{ 
    public string ReqId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BusinessDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CurrentDate{ get; set; }
}
```

So **Customer A** can only set values (or send values in request) `ReqId` and `BusinessDate` and **Customer B** send values `ReqId` and `CurrentDate`. As to proceed with business operation either of the date is required.

It's also previously decided which client will send which of the values, and this number of properties is large.

So I was thinking of creating a relatively small class which will be subset of `CustomRequest` class and sufficient enough to process business operations. And I can think of two options to proceed with that.

1. *Write code inside my controller action to create small sub set class
   and then call another method that expect only the subset class*
2. *Use Custom Model binders to create that small subset class and change the method signature*.

My question is:
What is the best way to handle this situation option 1 or 2 or any other option? Best way in terms of performance and customization option available (like in option 1, i don't think we can use `ModelState`)

Any help or guidance...

Comment: Have a look at this, it seems similar to what you are attempting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894272/controller-action-with-derived-classes

Comment: @Armand, thanks for looking at it, I have checked the link and yes it's seems similar  , and Accepted Answer is quite same to option 1 in our case. any idea how can we use model binders on this approach.

Comment: public class CustomRequest<T>
{
 public string ReqId { get; set; }
 public T respons{get;set}
}
public Class Name
{
   public DateTime? BusinessDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime? CurrentDate{ get; set; }
}  Try this one

Comment: I think this article covers it, I haven't used custom model binders before, but this should do the trick https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: From there you can use polymorphism to do the business logic

Comment: How did you decide the `client/tenant`? What is the limit for using the `CustomRequest` with all properties, for `valiation`, you could try [Custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-attributes)